# Checking union cases dynamically

Tags: f#

How do I match union cases ***dynamically*** in F# when there are value declarations?

Non working code:

```
let myShape = Shape.Square
expect myShape Shape.Circle 

type Shape =
   | Circle of int
   | Square of int
   | Rectangle of ( int * int )

let expect someShape someUnionCase =
    if not ( someShape = someUnionCase )
    then failwith ( sprintf "Expected shape %A. Found shape %A" someShape someUnionCase )

let myShape = Shape.Square
expect myShape Shape.Circle // Here I want to compare the value types, not the values
```

If my union cases did not declare values, this works using instantiation samples (which is not what I want):

```
let myShape = Shape.Square
expect myShape Shape.Circle 

type Shape =
   | Circle
   | Square
   | Rectangle

let expect someShape someUnionCase =
    if not ( someShape = someUnionCase )
    then failwith ( sprintf "Expected shape %A. Found shape %A" someShape someUnionCase )

let myShape = Shape.Square
expect myShape Shape.Circle // Comparing values instead of types
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the `expect` function in your example with e.g. `Shape.Square` as an argument, you're actually passing it a function that takes the arguments of the union case and builds a value.

Analyzing functions dynamically is quite difficult, but you could instead pass it concrete values (like `Shape.Square(0)`) and check that their shape is the same (ignore the numeric arguments). This can be done using F# reflection. The `FSharpValue.GetUnionFields` function returns the name of the case of an object, together with `obj[]` of all the arguments (which you can ignore):

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let expect (someShape:'T) (someUnionCase:'T) = 
  if not (FSharpType.IsUnion(typeof<'T>)) then
    failwith "Not a union!"
  else
    let info1, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(someShape, typeof<'T>)
    let info2, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(someUnionCase, typeof<'T>)
    if not (info1.Name = info2.Name) then
      failwithf "Expected shape %A. Found shape %A" info1.Name info2.Name
```

If you now compare `Square` with `Circle`, the function throws, but if you compare two `Squares`, it works (even if the values are different):

```
let myShape = Shape.Square(10)
expect myShape (Shape.Circle(0)) // Throws
expect myShape (Shape.Square(0)) // Fine
```

If you wanted to avoid creating concrete values, you could also use F# quotations and write something like `expect <@ Shape.Square @> myValue`. That's a bit more complex, but maybe nicer. Some examples of quotation processing [can be found here](http://fssnip.net/tags/quotations).

Comment: Wow, that was ugly. I expect a terrible performance hit. I'm using it to verify a parsed AST tree for expected used code organization.

Comment: Given John Palmers insight that all I want to do is to compare two integers that I have at hand, using reflection or run time IL code generation seems absurd

Comment: This all dates back to types not being represented by values (objects) in the CLR. Which dates back to the fact that Anders Heijsbergs Cool (later to be C#) was modeled after Java. Which dates back to Gosling using constructors instead of class methods, missing the fact that Bjarne Strousup did the typeless nightmare because a type object just did not fit the original cfront C++ to C translation tool. Things like 'constructors and 'static' instead of type member functions was a COMPROMISE because of cfront. Shame on Gosling and Anders for not understanding the motivation of the typeless type.

Comment: @JoachimWester I guess you can take quite a different point of view depending on whether you see the problem from an OO (i.e. SmallTalk) perspective or from a functionel (i.e. ML) perspective.

Comment: I believe that for functional programming, the inability to treat a type as a value is just as wrong as in an OO language, although the consecquences are graver in OO.

Comment: And yes, you are right, I really miss SmallTalk (if it wasn't for the non type safe late binding). The problem is that the careless idea of transferring the cfront type system into new languages is so stupid. Imagine what a struggle to come up with the constructor call chain when there was no type object when Bjarne created C++. In no way would he have neglected the new operator as being a member function if he had the option (i.e. if he has creating a new compiler instead of a C pre compiler as was the case with cfront). Static function polymorphisism and no need for special constructors.

Comment: The problem with treating types as values is that you then need a meta-type for types (and meta-meta-type for this meta-type) and you cannot do much with the meta-type (if it generates a type, you cannot know what this value - type - is statically). Unless, of course, you treat types and values as equal, but languages that do this aren't really practically useful yet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type

Comment: There are many languages that uses the approach as treating types as regular values. Smalltalk is only one of them. The problem of having a type of the type of the types type is simply to disallowing it at compile when applicable and at runtime (throwing an exception when you recursively retrieve type of type and reaching beyond the type of the type of Type).

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, this can be done very easily in C#, but the F# compiler will not allow you to call the functions - which seems odd.

The spec says that a discriminated union will have (section 8.5.3):

> One CLI instance property u.Tag for each case C that fetches or
>   computes an integer tag corresponding to the case.

So we can write your expect function in C# trivially

```
public bool expect (Shape expected, Shape actual)
{
    expected.Tag == actual.Tag;
}
```

It is an interesting question as to why this can't be done in F# code, the spec doesn't appear to give a good reason why.

Comment: Really usefull information :-) How annoying then to have to resort to runtime code generation or reflection

Comment: I'm happy the F# implementation does materialize types in this way. It is a petty that we are stuck with the original C#/VB type philosophy in the .Net languages though

Comment: @JoachimWester: it's not C#/VB type philosophy, but how the CLS was designed. A .NET-based language obviously has to correspond to the CLS at some level.

Comment: @ShdNx Anders Cool project (became C#) decided on the Java model. The CLR however, does not have the problem. Your compiler can create a singleton object for each class and apply all static methods as member functions on that singleton (including new). The problem is not the CLR, but it is the .NET framework classes and the C# compiler than does not use this singleton type object. So I disagree, it is original philosophy and not the CLR. The CLR is as it should be IMHO.

Comment: @JoachimWester: where did you see me mention the CLR? I agree, the CLR couldn't care less about these things. However the CLS (Common Language Specification) was designed like that.

Answer (score 1):

I use the same pattern to implement type checking in HLVM. For example, when indexing into an array I check that the type of the expression is an array ignoring the element type. But I don't use reflection as the other answers have suggested. I just do something like this:

```
let eqCase = function
  | Circle _, Circle _
  | Square _, Square _
  | Rectangle _, Rectangle _ -> true
  | _ -> false
```

Usually in a more specific form like this:

```
let isCircle = function
  | Circle _ -> true
  | _ -> false
```

You could also do:

```
let (|ACircle|ASquare|ARectangle|) = function
  | Circle _ -> ACircle
  | Square _ -> ASquare
  | Rectangle _ -> ARectangle
```

If you do decide to go the reflection route and performance is an issue (reflection is *unbelievably slow*) then use the precomputed forms:

```
let tagOfShape =
  Reflection.FSharpValue.PreComputeUnionTagReader typeof<Shape>
```

This is over 60× faster than direct reflection.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE** this has a caveat. See UPDATE below.

It appears that union cases are implemented as nested classes of the union type (type name: `FSI_0006+Shape+Square`). So given a union type instance, checking the type of the instance by `obj.GetType()` is sufficient.

```
let expect (someShape:'T) (someUnionCase:'T) = 
    if (someShape.GetType() <> someUnionCase.GetType()) then failwith "type not compatible"

type Shape =
   | Circle of int
   | Square of int
   | Rectangle of ( int * int )

let myShape = Shape.Square 12
printfn "myShape.GetType(): %A" (myShape.GetType())
expect myShape (Shape.Circle 5)
```

This outputs:

```
myShape.GetType(): FSI_0006+Shape+Square
System.Exception: type not compatible
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.FailWith[T](String message)
>    at FSI_0006.expect[T](T someShape, T someUnionCase)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0006>.$FSI_0006.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

I just don't know if this approach is considered implementation dependent, i.e., some platform/runtime implements this differently such that the types of two different union case objects are the same.

**UPDATE**

OK I found the above doesn't work for union type with cases that don't take parameters. In that case, the implementation of the cases are different and `.GetType()` always gives the union type's declaring type. The below code demonstrates this:

```
type Foo = A|B|C
type Bar = X|Y|Z of int

let getType (x:obj) = x.GetType()
let p (x:obj) = printfn "%A" x

A |> getType |> p
B |> getType |> p
C |> getType |> p
X |> getType |> p
Y |> getType |> p
Z 7 |> getType |> p
```

This gives:

```
FSI_0004+Foo
FSI_0004+Foo
FSI_0004+Foo
FSI_0004+Bar+_X
FSI_0004+Bar+_Y
FSI_0004+Bar+Z
```

The more general alternative, as mentioned in another answer, would be to convert the case instances into tags:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

// more general solution but slower due to reflection
let obj2Tag<'t> (x:obj) =
    FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typeof<'t>) |> fst |> (fun (i: UnionCaseInfo) -> i.Tag)

[A;B;C;A] |> List.map obj2Tag<Foo> |> p
[X;Y;Z 2; Z 3; X] |> List.map obj2Tag<Bar> |> p
```

This gives:

```
[0; 1; 2; 0]
[0; 1; 2; 2; 0]
```

This should be considerably slower if operated on large amount of objects, as it's heavily depend on reflection.